# Sync-rsync keeps appending my localPath (including `Users/LOCAL_USER` folder) to my remotePath

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to use the `sync-rsync` VSCode extension to sync my local folder to my remote server.

This is my config on VSCode `settings.json` file:

```
"sync-rsync.onSaveIndividual": true,
"sync-rsync.sites": [
  "localPath": "/",
  "remotePath":  "user@machine:/REMOTE_PATH/"
]
```

But the resulting `rsync` call I'm getting is appending my local user folder to my remote path.

```
rsync -rlptzv   /Users/LOCAL_USER/LOCAL_PATH   /REMOTE_PATH/Users/LOCAL_USER/LOCAL_PATH
```

I don't want `Users/LOCAL_USER` to be included in my `remotePath`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue:

```
"sync-rsync.onSaveIndividual": true,
"sync-rsync.sites": [
  "localPath": "/Users/LOCAL_USER/LOCAL_PATH",
  "remotePath":  "user@machine:/REMOTE_PATH/"
]
```